# Finding Limit point of given sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find the limit point of the following sequence $\langle f_n\rangle$, where

$$f_n=\begin{cases}
\tfrac{n+1}{n}& \text{ when }n=3m,\\
\tfrac{n+2}{2n}& \text{ when }n=3m+1,\\
\tfrac{1}{n+1}& \text{ when }n=3m+2.
\end{cases}$$

I tried finding the sequence separately for the three given conditions. Like the sequence (1) seemed to cluster around 1.1. However, i doubt of i am approaching it the right way. Some hint on this will be helpful

Comment: Some MathJax advice:

`<` and `>` mean "less than" and "greater than", and produce spacing correct for that meaning only; to make angle brackets, use `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thanks, Fixed it !!, the given problem is a single function, can you please show me how to put them together like we do using a big bracket on copy ?

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

The third variant ($n=3m+2$) obviously converges to $0$. The other variants can be rewritten as $1+\frac1n$ and $\frac12+\frac1n$, respectively, so these converge to $1$ and $\frac12$, respectively. So far we have found the limit points $\{0,\frac12,1\}$. There cannot be more limit points because any convergent subsequence has infinitely many terms in common with at least one of the three interwoven subsequences, hence must converge to the same limit as that subsequence.

Comment: I didn;t understand the reason for why there wont be more limit points.

Comment: sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ has only 1 limit point ie 0 and so the sequence $c+\frac{1}{n}$ will have only one limit point ie c.